# Spring Boot + MongoDB: How to reuse connections

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I'm using SpringBoot + MongoDB. I created my object as follows.
I am able to @Autowrite the DocumentStoreConfig object in my Service/Controller and make calls to Mongo.

Sample call:

```
    @Autowired
    private DocumentStoreConfig docStoreConfig;
this.docStoreConfig.mongoClient().getDatabase("db_name").getCollection(collection).insertOne(doc);
```

Problem I see is that each call does a 'new' MongoClient and opens up a new connections.

What is the guidance on setting up a pool.. or reusing the same connection object rather than making the painful cost of opening a brand new connection.

```
@Configuration
public class DocumentStoreConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {


    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.uri}")
    private String connectionString;

    @Value("${documentstore.database}")
    private String databaseName;

    @Override
    public String getDatabaseName() {
        return this.databaseName;
}


    @Override
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        System.out.println("**** \n\n\n NEW MONGO \n\n\n");
        return new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(this.connectionString));
    }

    public MongoCollection<Document> getFailureCollection() {
        return this.mongoClient().getDatabase(this.databaseName).getCollection("failure");
    }

}
```